# What does the notation $\sum_i (A_i \times B_i)$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definition

I am reading some notes on measure theory and I came across the notation:
$\sum_i (A_i \times B_i)$.

Here $A_i$ is a subset of a set $X$ and $B_i$ is a subset of a set $Y$.

What is meant by this notation?

Comment: What notes? Are they available online?

Comment: Yes, Chris Almost measure theory notes, sorry I am on mobile so cannot give the link, but a google search works

Comment: I've found the paper and have also found the notation in the chapter about product measures.

Comment: It seems to be a disjoint union, or rather a union of disjoint sets (which is not the same as the construction "disjoint union"). The author also seems to mix the notations $\bigsqcup$ and $\sum$ for disjoint unions.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it means the set
\begin{align*}
\sum_i (A_i \times B_i) = \{(a,b) : a = \sum_i a_i, b = \sum_i b_i \text{ where }a_i \in A_i, b_i \in B_i\}
\end{align*}
i.e. the set of ordered pairs that can be written as a sum where the $i^{th}$ term in the sum is an element in $A_i \times B_i$.